# Understanding Entity ID when URI is URL should I use HTTP or HTTPS

Tags: security, single-sign-on, saml, okta

When setting up an SSO solution, in my case using Okta, there are the following elements to define:

IdP Server Issuer/Entity ID -  http://www.okta.com/dskjeoirueiuaksjdkfj
SP Issuer/Entity ID - http://www.myapp.com/IDP

Given that these are URIs I have read it doesn't matter if the protocol is defined as either http:// or https://.  I am trying to understand if this is true and if so why/why not.

I also read, while it technically does not matter if http:// or https:// is used, that https:// is more flexible.  However no explanation was given as to why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `entityID` is just the "handle" for your Identity Provider (IdP). It should be constant across all the Service Providers you interact with.

The [recommendation](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT/EntityNaming) is that you own the domain with a view to hosting your metadata at a resolvable uri.

The [UK federation explains](https://www.ukfederation.org.uk/content/Documents/EntityIDPolicy) that https is recommended because:

> https scheme entity IDs can be constructed to be compatible with
>   alternative metadata publishing schemes, such as that described in
>   section 4.1 of the SAML 2.0 metadata specification

For example, another federation might not publish your metadata if your `entityID` `uri` is resolvable to an `http` `url`. They may prefer `https`.

[SAML 2.0 metadata specification PDF](http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/35391/sstc-saml-metadata-errata-2.0-wd-04-diff.pdf)